# Reloading google maps places API on checkbox change

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

**Introduction**

I'm using the google maps Places API for a website. It lets a visitor see certain places near the location that he/she has chosen such as a bakery, cinema, school, busstation etc.

The problem is that the google maps places API only gets about 20 results at most, which causes a lot of places to be missing from the map even though they're within the specified radius (700 in this case).

What I came up with was using checkboxes to let the user select which places he/she wants to see.

The concept is very simple. The user clicks a checkbox and (by using jquery) populates an array. This array is used to call the API and load in the markers.

**The Problem**

The map seems to reload (it "flickers") but it only shows me the grocery_or_supermarket places (which are by default enabled and in the array so the user doesn't see an empty map).
I'm calling the `initialize()` function after changing a checkbox.
It's not changing the markers on the map or adding new ones which is what I want.

**The Code**

```
<script>
var q = jQuery.noConflict();
var selected = ["grocery_or_supermarket"];

q( document ).ready(function( q ) {
    q('.map-legenda').change(function() {
        var selected = [];
        q.each(q('.map-legenda input:checked'), function(a,b) {
            selected.push(q(b).val());
        });
        console.log(selected);
        initialize();
    });
});
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
var map;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var _lat = "<?php print($lat); ?>";
  var _long = "<?php print($long); ?>";

  var home = new google.maps.LatLng(_lat, _long);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: home,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    location: home,
    radius: 750,
    types: selected
  };

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

  var marker_home = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: home,
    icon: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/CH/lib/images/maps_icons/covers.png'
  });
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

var grocery_icon = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/CH/lib/images/maps_icons/grocerystore.png';
var school_icon = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/CH/lib/images/maps_icons/school.png';
var gym_icon = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/CH/lib/images/maps_icons/gym.png';
var treinstation_icon = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/CH/lib/images/maps_icons/treinstation.png';
var bakery_icon = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/CH/lib/images/maps_icons/bakery.png';
var bus_station_icon = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/CH/lib/images/maps_icons/busstation.png';
var convenience_store_icon = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/CH/lib/images/maps_icons/conv_store.png';
var movie_theater_icon = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/CH/lib/images/maps_icons/bios.png';
var park_icon = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/CH/lib/images/maps_icons/park.png';
var parking_icon = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/CH/lib/images/maps_icons/parking.png';

function createMarker(place) {
  var custom_icon;
  if(place.types.indexOf('grocery_or_supermarket') != -1) {
    custom_icon = grocery_icon;
  } else if(place.types.indexOf('gym') != -1) {
    custom_icon = gym_icon;
  } else if(place.types.indexOf('train_station') != -1) {
    custom_icon = treinstation_icon;
  } else if(place.types.indexOf('school') != -1) {
    custom_icon = school_icon;
  } else if(place.types.indexOf('bakery') != -1) {
    custom_icon = bakery_icon;
  } else if(place.types.indexOf('bus_station') != -1) {
    custom_icon = bus_station_icon;
  } else if(place.types.indexOf('convenience_store') != -1) {
    custom_icon = convenience_store_icon;
  } else if(place.types.indexOf('movie_theater') != -1) {
    custom_icon = movie_theater_icon;
  } else if(place.types.indexOf('park') != -1) {
    custom_icon = park_icon;
  } else if(place.types.indexOf('parking') != -1) {
    custom_icon = parking_icon;
  }

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    title: place.name,
    icon: custom_icon
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<br/>
<ul class="map-legenda">
  <li class="woning">
    <img width="32" height="32" alt="Woning" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/lib/images/maps_icons/covers.png">
    <?php echo icl_t('custom','Woning','Woning');?>
  </li>
  <li class="supermarkt">
    <img width="32" height="32" alt="Supermarkt" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/lib/images/maps_icons/grocerystore.png">
    <?php echo icl_t('custom','Supermarkt','Supermarkt');?><input type="checkbox" name="supermarkt" value="grocery_or_supermarket" checked>
  </li>
  <li class="parkeerplaats">
    <img width="32" height="32" alt="<?php echo icl_t('custom','Parking','Parking');?>" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/lib/images/maps_icons/parking.png">
    <?php echo icl_t('custom','Parking','Parking');?><input type="checkbox" name="parkeerplaats" value="parking">
  </li>  
  <li class="fitness">
    <img width="32" height="32" alt="Fitness" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/lib/images/maps_icons/gym.png">
    <?php echo icl_t('custom','Fitness','Fitness');?><input type="checkbox" name="fitness" value="gym">
      </li> 
    <li class="school">
    <img width="32" height="32" alt="School" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/lib/images/maps_icons/school.png">
    <?php echo icl_t('custom','School','School');?><input type="checkbox" name="school" value="school">
      </li>  
      <li class="bakkerij">
        <img width="32" height="32" alt="<?php echo icl_t('custom','Bakery','Bakery');?>" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/lib/images/maps_icons/bakery.png">
        <?php echo icl_t('custom','Bakery','Bakery');?><input type="checkbox" name="bakkerij" value="bakery">
      </li>
      <li class="busstation">
        <img width="32" height="32" alt="<?php echo icl_t('custom','Bus station','Bus station');?>" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/lib/images/maps_icons/busstation.png">
        <?php echo icl_t('custom','Bus station','Bus station');?><input type="checkbox" name="busstation" value="bus_station">
      </li>
      <li class="park">
        <img width="32" height="32" alt="<?php echo icl_t('custom','Park','Park');?>" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/lib/images/maps_icons/park.png">
        <?php echo icl_t('custom','Park','Park');?><input type="checkbox" name="park" value="park">
      </li>
      <li class="bios">
        <img width="32" height="32" alt="<?php echo icl_t('custom','Movie theater','Movie theater');?>" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/lib/images/maps_icons/bios.png">
    <?php echo icl_t('custom','Movie theater','Movie theater');?><input type="checkbox" name="bios" value="movie_theater">
      </li>
      <li class="buurtwinkel">
        <img width="32" height="32" alt="<?php echo icl_t('custom','Convenience store','Convenience store');?>" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/lib/images/maps_icons/conv_store.png">
        <?php echo icl_t('custom','Convenience store','Convenience store');?><input type="checkbox" name="buurtwinkel" value="convenience_store">
      </li>
      <li class="treinstation">
        <img width="32" height="32" alt="Trein" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/lib/images/maps_icons/treinstation.png">
        <?php echo icl_t('custom','Trein','Trein');?><input type="checkbox" name="treinstation" value="train_station">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you say `var selected = []` in your `change` handler instead of just `selected = []`?

Comment: @AustinMullins Does it really matter? I'll change it just in case.

Comment: I'd say it does. `var` creates a new variable with the same name as your global `selected`. The `selected` array inside your change handler is inaccessible to your `initialize` function.

Comment: @AustinMullins Aaaand apparently it does matter. It works now :I. Go ahead and add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, `var` declares a new variable inside a certain scope. By declaring `var selected = []` inside your `change` handler, you created a new variable that was inaccessible to your `initialize` function. Removing the `var` in your change handler causes it to modify the global `selected` array.

As @duncan pointed out in a comment, perhaps a better way to achieve the same result would be to take `selected` out of global scope and pass it as a parameter to `initialize`.

```
<script>
    q( document ).ready(function( q ) {
        q('.map-legenda').change(function() {
            var selected = [];
            q.each(q('.map-legenda input:checked'), function(a,b) {
                selected.push(q(b).val());
            });
            console.log(selected);
            initialize(selected);
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    var map;
    var infowindow;

    function initialize(selected) {
        ...
```

Comment: Rather than make `selected` a global variable, I think it would be preferable to pass it as a parameter to the `initialize` function

Comment: also to pass the initial version of the `selected` array to that function (rather than have logic to deal with what happens if it doesn't exist) you could add a closure to your event listener: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() { initialize(["grocery_or_supermarket"]);});`